# Could not assign string to MenuItem's text property

Tags: javascript, qml

Working with `qml` `Menu`, trying to assign string from model to `MenuItem's` text property and got `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`

```
MouseArea {
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        anchors.fill: parent;

        onClicked: contextMenu.popup();


        Menu {
            id: contextMenu
            property var strings: ["...", "...", "..."]

            Instantiator {
                model: contextMenu.strings
                MenuItem {
                    text: model.text
                }


                onObjectAdded: contextMenu.insertItem(index, object)
                onObjectRemoved: contextMenu.removeItem(object)
            }
        }
    }
```

`MenuItems` has instantiated but with empty text

Answer (score 2):

Your model doesn't have a `text` property. You can access your strings by using the `index` attached property:

```
MenuItem {
    text: contextMenu.strings[index]
}
```

Comment: Thanx for answer , I have tried ```MenuItem {
    text: modelData
}``` also worked